# Nginx / Apache / WSGI / Django - Unexpected raising 500 errors (499 on Nginx)

Tags: django, apache, nginx, mod-wsgi

I have problems with my Django server on Webfaction hosting. For some request (about 1.000 request from 500.000 per day) I can see errors in access logs. In nginx log I can see requests with code "499", in apache log they have "500" error code.

Weird is that I do not see any problems in my django logs (usually I receiving mail with excepting stacktrace). Can you help me, what can cause this strange behaviour?

I start to investigate logs after receiving problems with exceeding my hosting memory limit. Seems my app has some memory leaks, because I can see that used memory slowly rising. So I tryed to quickfix by optimize my wsgi processes, thread and try to set maximum-request param. After this I will investigate cause of memory leak.

My infrastructure is following:

- Nginx - frontend server (this is operated by Webfaction)
- Apache/2.4.16, with mod_wsgi 4.4.13/Python 3.4
- Django 1.8.12

My httpd.conf is following:

```
ServerRoot "/home/quick/webapps/citaty/apache2"

LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule dir_module        modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module        modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module       modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule rewrite_module    modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module   modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule wsgi_module       modules/mod_wsgi.so
LoadModule unixd_module      modules/mod_unixd.so

LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t %{Host}i \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %T %D" combined
CustomLog /home/quick/logs/user/access_citaty.log combined
ErrorLog /home/quick/logs/user/error_citaty.log

Listen 21628
KeepAlive Off
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1
ServerLimit 1
StartServers 1
MaxRequestWorkers 10
MinSpareThreads 1
MaxSpareThreads 5
ThreadsPerChild 10
MaxRequestsPerChild 1000

WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGILazyInitialization On

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName domain.com

    CustomLog /home/quick/logs/user/access_citaty.log combined
    ErrorLog /home/quick/logs/user/error_citaty.log

    WSGIDaemonProcess citaty processes=5 threads=1 maximum-requests=1000 python-path=/home/quick/webapps/citaty:/home/quick/webapps/citaty/lib/python3.4/site-packages display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup citaty
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/quick/webapps/citaty/apache2/conf/citaty.wsgi

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName domain2.com

    CustomLog /home/quick/logs/user/access_citaty_laska.log combined
    ErrorLog /home/quick/logs/user/error_citaty_laska.log

    WSGIDaemonProcess citaty_laska processes=1 threads=1 maximum-requests=1000 python-path=/home/quick/webapps/citaty:/home/quick/webapps/citaty/lib/python3.4/site-packages display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup citaty_laska
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/quick/webapps/citaty/apache2/conf/citaty_laska.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

My django logging settings is following:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/home/quick/logs/user/django_citaty.log',
        },
        'file_jobs': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/home/quick/logs/user/django_jobs.log',
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'mail_admins'],
        },
        'py.warnings': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
        },
        'citaty.sources.crawlers.base': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['file_jobs', 'console'],
        },

    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used to face this problem a month back. All of a sudden nginx would start throwing 499 error code.

When client makes a request, nginx asks uwsgi for response, sometimes uwsgi takes too long to respond, user thinks that the request is slow and tries to refresh or makes another call, nginx then throws 499 error code.

**Possible Reasons:-**

1. Uwsgi workers consume quite a bit of RAM. Check how many workers are there in uwsgi configuration file. Make sure to limit uwsgi worker process to an appropriate number based on your system settings.
2. Increase nginx worker connections. Default is very low. This causes connections drops which result in 500 errors too. Check connection_timeout settings in nginx. its generally 60 secs. You can reduce it to 25 sec or so to make sure nginx is ready to accept more connections.

I fixed this issue by increasing server RAM and also added a load balancer to make sure there is no heavy load on one server.
Also, made some changes to uwsgi ini file and nginx.conf

Below is my uwsgi settings file-

```
[uwsgi]
project =xxxxxx
base = /home/ubuntu

chdir = %(base)/xxxxxxx/server
home = %(base)/envs/api
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
cheaper-algo = spare
cheaper = 2
cheaper-initial = 3
cheaper-step = 2
processes = 20
workers = 20
max-requests = 1000

socket = %(base)/xxxx/server/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
logto=/tmp/uwsgi.log
```

My nginx.conf-

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 2048;
    # multi_accept on;
}
```

**Bottomline** - This is almost always a memory issue. Recheck your code for memory leaks. make sure DEBUG=False in settings.py in production. Use cache to reduce server response times.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I checked logged response time for error requests, seems in this case is not problem of slow response time (error response takes under 0,5 sec). But may be there is problem in number of workers as you wrote. I will try to rise number of processes and thread and I will see.